# Do While LOOP - best approach

Tags: php, loops, mkdir, do-while

I have the right PHP scripting to create a random number and make a new folder on the server with that # as it's name. If the folder exists the script stops. What I can't figure out though is how to direct the script to generate a new random # if the folder already exists and try again until it finds a unused number/folder. I think a `do while` is what I'm looking for but not sure if I have written it correctly or not (Don't want to test it on the server for fear of creating a forever looping `mkdir` command).

Here is the one off code being used

```
<?php
$clientid = rand(1,5);
while (!file_exists("clients/$clientid"))
{
mkdir("clients/$clientid", 0755, true);
exit("Your new business ID is($clientid)");
}
echo ("The client id is $clientid");
?>
```

Here is the `do while` I am contemplating - is this correct or do I need to do this a different way?

```
<?php

$clientid = rand(1,5);

do {mkdir("clients/$clientid", 0755, true);
    exit("Your new business ID is($clientid)");}

while (!file_exists("clients/$clientid"));
echo ("The client id is $clientid");

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you only generate a new number once, outside the loop. This means that you end up with a loop that never terminates. Invert the loop and and generate a new number each iteration:

```
$clientid = rand(1,5);
while (file_exists("clients/$clientid"))
{
    // While we are in here, the file exists. Generate a new number and try again.
    $clientid = rand(1,5);
}

// We are now guaranteed that we have a unique filename.
mkdir("clients/$clientid", 0755, true);
exit("Your new business ID is($clientid)");
```

Comment: awesome that did work alex and I appreciate it - on a side note, my random number will be set to 10k to 90k so it has a LONG way before no available numbers - but just to cover all bases, would using logic similar to MadDokMike suggestion on the safety count be the way to error out of the script with a exit() if all numbers are used?

Comment: @user2065226 Yep. In case all possible combinations are used, you will need something else to break the loop. A counter is one way.

Comment: Putting in a hard limit of 10000 loops might be a good idea just in case. Code like this has a way of getting forgotten and tripping up someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<?php
$filename = md5(time().rand()) . ".txt";
while(is_file("clients/$filename")){
    $filename = md5(time().rand()) . ".txt";
}
touch("clients/$filename");
```

Answer (score 0):

useful tip for when your testing code on a while loop; create variable as a safety count and increment it then if your other logic causes an infinite problem it breaks out, like this:

```
$safetyCount = 0;
while (yourLogic && $safeCount < 500){

//more of your logic
$safetyCount++;
}
```

obviously if you need 500 lower / higher then set it to whatever, this just makes sure you'll not kill your machine. :)

Comment: thank you - not enough reputation to vote it up - sorry, but thank you for that idea, I'll use it in the future